# RHEL 8.1 Kickstart cannot find ks.cfg

Tags: linux, rhel8

I'm having an issue with the RHEL 8.1 kickstart via NFS:

NFS share: 192.168.x.x:/export/nfs/kickstart/rhel8

Kickstart File: 192.168.x.x:/export/nfs/kickstart/rhel8/ks.cfg

It appears that Anaconda(?) is mounting the NFS directory locally under /run/install/repo -- I can check that the mount is there and all files on the NFS share are available at that location.
However, Anaconda seems to be looking for the ks.cfg file at /run/install/repo/ks.cfg/ks.cfg (Yes, there is an extra "ks.cfg" in the path)

Is anyone else getting this issue kickstarting via NFS?  If so, does anyone know of a workaround or fix?

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating directory called **ks.cfg** on the NFS and moving the file there. You might want to check for an unnecessary "**/**" in specifying your path somewhere.

Comment: I have tried a dozen different filenames, a dozen different ways, and the kickstart always looks for "/run/install/repo/<ks_config>/<ks_config>"  when using the boot option "inst.ks=nfs:<IP>:/nfs_share_path/<ks_config>"
I did as you suggested -- put ks.cfg in a directory named ks.cfg and it did find it withhout modifying my inst.ks path.
So - workaround works.  Thanks!  I think this is a bug in the RHEL8.1 kickstart, though.

Answer (score 0):

According to RH tech support, it's an issue described in the following article:
https://access.redhat.com/solutions/3938501

I will change my kickstart to use a separate directory and see if it works.